# The best JSF coding pattern for editing JPA entities using @RequestScoped only

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I am in a project where I will write a lot of pages like this, so I want to use the most efficient (to write) coding pattern.

Background:  In the past I have used CODI's @ViewAccessScoped to preserve state between requests, and more recently I have started using flash scoped objects to save state.   I can't use JSF @ViewScoped because I use CDI and they don't play well together.   So I want to see if I can do this with only @RequestScoped backing beans.

The page is designed like this (the p namespace is Primefaces):

```
            <f:metadata>
                <f:viewParam name="ID" value="#{backing.id}" />
            </f:metadata>

                ....

            <h1>Edit Object Page</h1>

            <h:form id="formObj" rendered="#{backing.accessOK}">

                <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Field #1:"/>
                    <p:inputText value="#{backing.record.field1}" />

                          (more input fields)

                    <h:outputLabel value="Action:" />
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <p:commandButton value="Save"
                                         action="#{backing.save}"
                                         />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" action="backing.cancel" />
                    </h:panelGroup>

                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="true" />

            </h:form>
```

If the page is requested, the method **accessOK()** has the ability to keep the **h:form** from being rendered.  Instead, the **p:messages** is shown with whatever **FacesMessage**(s) the **accessOK()** method cares to set.

The pattern for the bean **backing** looks like this:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Backing {

    private long id;
    private SomeJPAEntity record;
    private Boolean accessOK;

    public long getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(long value) { id = value; }

    public boolean accessOK() {
        if (accessOK != null) return accessOK;

        if (getRecord() == null) {
             // add a FacesMessage that explains the record
             // does not exist
             return accessOK = false;  // note single =
        }

        // do any other access checks, such as write permissions

        return accessOK = true;
    }

    public SomeJPAEntity getRecord() {
        if (record != null) return record;

        if (getId() > 0) record = // get the record from DB
        else record = new SomeJPAEntity();

        return record;
    }

    public String execute() {

         if (!accessOK()) return null;   // bad edit

         // do other integrity checks here.  If fail, set FacesMessages
         // and return null;

         if (getId() > 0) // merge the record back into the data base
         else  // persist the record

    }

}
```

Here is what goes wrong with this model.  When the Save button is clicked, a new instance of **Backing** is built, and then there are a lot of calls to the **getRecord()** getter *before* the **setID()** setter is called.  So the logic in **getRecord()** breaks because it cannot rely on the **id** property being valid when it is called.

When this was a **@ViewAccessScoped** (or **ViewScoped**) backing bean, then both the **id** and **record** properties are already set when the form is processed with the **commandButton**.   Alternatively you can save those properties in flash storage but that has its own problems I want to avoid.

So is there a way to make this programming model work within the specification?

***UPDATE:***

I have a work-around that empirically allows this to work without resorting to either flash or view-scoped variants.  As mentioned above, when the form is processed there are a number of calls to **getRecord()** *before* the first call to **setId()**.   Then at last the **save()** method is called.

What I do is modify **setId()** as follows:

```
public void setId(long value) {
  id = value;
  record = null;
}
```

This forces the **getRecord()** to re-compute (i.e. fetch/build) the property **record**, then subsequent calls work.  Specifically the **save()** method is entered with the object properly initialized including the contents of the **record** entity.   I have no idea what all the prior calls to **getRecord()** were for.

At this point what I also don't know I can rely on is whether all the values written into the **record** entity will be transferred from the **UIinput** components *after* **getId()** is set.  If so, then I can use this pattern.  Is this controlled by the specification or is it working just by luck?

Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to stop using CODI's scope(s)? Did you encounter a problem with them?

Comment: @MikeBraun I had concerns about its portability to containers other than Glassfish.  It also has a number of different modules which are supposed to work independently but didn't, which made me concerned about its stability to deploy.   But the real reason is I wanted to get this done with RequestScoped only to reduce the load on the server when you have potentially thousands of users with edit screens open.  Nonetheless if I can't get this code pattern to work robustly that is what I will go back to.

Comment: CODI and DeltaSpike are the best portable CDI extensions you can get for Glassfish. I'm using CODI in many production projects together with different EE6 servers.

Comment: I see. You might be interested in hearing that in JSF 2.2 the view scope will support CDI beans. Having much data in memory does save you those thousands of trips to a DB if thousands of users have edit screens open and often do a postback.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can feel safe with CODI (or rather up and coming DeltaSpike) I have used both well with Tomcat. And they will support practically all.

Deltaspike is working on the JSF module right now and there's a lot of activity and when that brew is done I'm sure you will be comfortable with it. Each module of deltaspike is production ready as a separate even though the project is still incubating.

Now for your actual problem I couldn't come up with anything not already suggested by you.

But I wonder, is this one of those cases were one might care for a binding on `f:viewParam`? I am not sure because I almost never used bindings.

Answer (score 1):

CODI and DeltaSpike enable @ViewScoped for CDI. The Flash-Scope in JSF < 2.2 is utterly broken with multiple windows. The only reason I see to move away from CODI is a migration to DeltaSpike and until it's ready you can use both in parallel.